SQL Procedure for Secret Santa Draw Allows Self-Gifting
I've developed a SQL stored procedure intended to automate a Secret Santa draw among a group of people. The procedure is supposed to randomly assign each person someone else to gift, without anyone gifting themselves. However, I've encountered a problem where it's possible for individuals to end up being assigned to gift themselves, which is not desired in a Secret Santa setup.
Here's the SQL code I'm using:
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS AMIGOINVISIBLE;

USE AMIGOINVISIBLE;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CaseA(
     id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
     people VARCHAR(50),
     peopleToGift VARCHAR(50)  );

INSERT INTO CaseA (people, peopleToGift) 
VALUES  ('a.tomas', NULL), ('g.rubio', NULL), ('a.pulido', NULL), ('m.fabrega.1', NULL), ('d.lazaro', NULL), ('c.albinya', NULL), ('b.gomez', NULL),`
 `('j.espinoza', NULL), ('j.aguilera', NULL), ('j.da.silva.1', NULL), ('a.chamorro', NULL);

DELIMITER //

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE randomizePeople()
 BEGIN
     DECLARE times INT;
     DECLARE Counter INT;
     DECLARE random1 INT;
     DECLARE random2 INT;
     DECLARE aux INT;
     DECLARE position INT;
     DECLARE peopleToGift VARCHAR(50);

     SELECT COUNT(*) INTO times FROM CaseA;
     DROP TABLE IF EXISTS order;
     CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS order (
         id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
         Number INT
     );
     SET Counter = 1;
     WHILE Counter <= times DO
         INSERT INTO order (Number) VALUES (Counter);
         SET Counter = Counter + 1;
     END WHILE;

     SET Counter = 1;

     WHILE Counter <= times DO
         SET random1 = FLOOR(RAND() * times) + 1;
         SET random2 = FLOOR(RAND() * times) + 1;

         SELECT Number INTO aux FROM order WHERE id = random1;
         UPDATE order SET Number = (SELECT Number FROM order WHERE id = random2) WHERE id = random1;
         UPDATE order SET Number = aux WHERE id = random2;

         SET Counter = Counter + 1;
     END WHILE;

     SET Counter = 1;

     WHILE Counter <= times DO
         SELECT Number INTO position FROM order WHERE id = Counter;
         SELECT people INTO peopleToGift FROM CaseA WHERE id = position;
         SELECT position, peopleToGift;

         UPDATE CaseA SET peopleToGift = peopleToGift WHERE id = Counter;
         SET Counter = Counter + 1;
     END WHILE;
END
//  DELIMITER;
DELIMITER ;


You can do this by first randomly assigning a row number to each person and storing it in a table:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS RandomOrder;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS RandomOrder (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    people VARCHAR(50),
    RowNumber INT,
    TotalCount INT
);
INSERT RandomOrder (id, people, RowNumber, TotalCount)
SELECT  id, 
        People,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RAND()) AS RowNumber,
        COUNT(*) OVER() AS TotalCount
FROM    CaseA;

Then you can just pair each person on the next person, e.g. RowNumber 1 with RowNumber2 etc, which ensures nobody can be paired with themselves. The only thing to note is that you need to pair the last row with the first, so you need to use the modulus operator on the join to do this, so I have added TotalCount to the above select to use there..
As a select this would look like this:
SELECT r1.id, r1.people, r1.RowNumber, r2.people AS peopleToGift
FROM RandomOrder AS r1
 INNER JOIN RandomOrder AS r2
    ON r2.RowNumber = (r1.RowNumber % r1.TotalCount) + 1
ORDER BY r1.id;

Or to update the base table itself you can convert this into an update as follows:
UPDATE CaseA
SET PeopleToGift = (    SELECT r2.People
                        FROM    RandomOrder AS r1
                               INNER JOIN RandomOrder AS r2
                                  ON r2.RowNumber = (r1.RowNumber % r1.TotalCount) + 1
                        WHERE   r1.id = CaseA.id
                    );

Example on SQLFiddle
